# Snapshot html 5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, snapshot

Here my code to take snapshot 300px/300px of my body.

```
    html2canvas(document.body, {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
      },
      width: 300,
      height: 300
    });
```

to test it i just put a a  like this

```
<a href="#" onclick="html2canvas(element, options);"> CANVAS </a>
```

But when I click can't see anything... Do I have to put a tag  of what I want to snapshot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of your code is not a declaration of a function.
Try with the following:

```
function performScreenshot(element) {
    html2canvas(element, {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        },
        width: 300,
        height: 300
    });
}
```

then call

```
<a href="#" onclick="performScreenshot(document.body);"> CANVAS </a>
```

Remember that "All the images that the script uses need to reside under the same origin for it to be able to read them without the assistance of a proxy" ( [html2canvas documentation](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html) )

Answer (score 1):

In your `onclick` you are passing element and options which is supposed to be an element (eg. document.body) and the option which is the second parameter in the `html2canvas` method.

If you are using jquery with the html2canvas.js, you can do something like following :-

This is the link that you click on to get the snapshot

```
<a href="#" id="snapshot">Test snapshot</a>
```

and this is what the script looks like

```
<script>
    $("#snapshot").click(function()
    {
        html2canvas(document.body,
        {
            onrendered: function(canvas)
            {
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            },
            width: 300,
            height: 300
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now is my right code, it works.

```
$(document).ready(function Canvas(){
   html2canvas($('#col2Game'), {
      onrendered: function (canvas) {
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
      }
   });
});
```

**I have my get_uploads.php file**

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$folder = 'uploads';
$handle = opendir($folder);

while(($file = readdir($handle)) !== false){
    if($file != '.' && $file != '..'){

        $nameFile = explode('.',$file);

        if($nameFile[0] == $id)
        {
            echo '<img src="'.$folder.'/'.$file.'?time='.time().'"/>';
            exit();
        }
    }
}

echo 'error';
```

**with my upload.php file**

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id= $_GET['id'];

    $folder = 'uploads/';
    $filename = $id.'.jpg';
    $input_con = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $file_path = $folder.$filename;

    file_put_contents($file_path, $input_con);
}
```

But how put my canvas snapshot into uploads folder?